# What is the proper name for this oscilloscope probe accessory?

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

These used to come standard in the accessory pack that comes with a new o'scope probe, but they haven't been included in quite some time.  They are very useful for checking certain test points, and we are starting to run out.  We would like to buy more, but we aren't sure what the proper name for them is and we haven't been able to find a supplier.  Any ideas?[image]

Comment: A probe extension?

Comment: Is it just an extension? either way. I would go to digikey and look for Test leads kits and assortments. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/test-and-measurement/test-leads-kits-assortments/628 they have a huge assortment of oscilloscopes accessory, leads and kits. If you see a picture which has the part you are looking for you can open the datasheet or catalog of the vendor/kit and find the name of this appropriate part.

Comment: Interesting. I was working with all kinds of oscilloscopes for nearly 50 years, and never seen this kind of "extension" before... It looks more likely as a DMM accessory. Some measurements of ID and OD would be quite helpful.

Comment: It is an extension.  It is 2 3/8" long and 1/4" at its widest point.  I looked at digikey before I came here and couldn't find anything like it on their website; I had hoped someone here would know.  Thanks.

Comment: Its for probing at odd angles, and for penetrating insulating coatings.

Comment: What about using a passive probe and just pulling off the probe hat?

Comment: Can you contact the manufacturer of the scope which used to include the part you show?

Answer (score 1):

Test Probe Tip. Took some digging but this shows what you need I'm sure:
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/test-and-measurement/test-probe-tips/622?k=probe%20tip